# Is there an effective way to tell whether two homogeneous polynomials are isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, reference-request, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

> Let $f,g\in \mathbb C[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_d$ be two given homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$. We say they are isomorphic if they differ by a linear coordinates change, i.e. a natural action by some element in $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbb C)$. I would like to know that, is there an effective way to tell whether two homogeneous polynomials are isomorphic?

I know the Torelli theorem says for curves we can just compute the Jacobian, and there is also a general Torelli theorem works for hypersurfaces. However, it only says the isomorphism classes are determined by some ring structures, and it is still not easy to tell whether two ring structures are isomophic. I would like to know if there are some numbers we can really compute.

Comment: Probably not. Even in the case of $n=3$, if we make $d$ large, this is a problem that's at least as hard as asking when two high-genus plane curves are isomorphic, which you may need up to $3\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}-3$ invariants to do.

Comment: @KReiser I see this is the dimension of the moduli space. But do there exist such invariants we can really compute from the coefficients of a plane curve?